# Heading numbering is not sequencing

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I cannot seem to make numbering work in word 2013.  creating a new template and this is what I want:

1.0 Topic
1.1 Sub Topic
1.1.1 Sub sub topic
2.0 Topic
2.1 sub topic
2.2.2 sub sub topic

but what I am getting is:

1.0 Topic
1.1 Sub Topic
1.1.1 Sub sub topic
2.0 Topic
1.2 sub topic
1.1.2 sub sub topic

Comment: Restart the numbering as needed for Topic 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a heading in the Style Gallery, **Modify -> Format -> Numbering - Define New Number Format**

In the number format field, you can add additional characters on either side of the greyed-out number that's that is already. That greyed out digit is the one that will increment each time you add consecutive headings of that style.

In the screenshot, for example, you'll see that the third digit in the Number format field is greyed out. Set up this way, that third digit will increase by 1 for each consecutive level 3 heading.

In your example, you seem to skip a few in the series. I'm not sure if that is intentional, but you should be able to get the result you are looking for using a combination of digits on either side of that greyed-out number in the Number Format field.

[image]